# Korn Shell - want to convert date/time from America/Chicago timezone to Australia/Sydney timezone

Tags: linux

I get a date and time that is in the 'America/Chicago' time zone.

My local time zone is 'Australia/Melbourne'.

I need to convert the date/time that is in the 'America/Chicago' time zone to the local timezone('Australia/Melbourne')

I know how to convert a date/time from the local timezone to a date/time in another timezone:

```
datep="140501 17:31:22"

dateus=`TZ=America/Chicago date -d @$(date +%s -d "${datep}")`

echo ${dateus}

Thu May 1 02:31:22 CDT 2014
```

However I do not know how to convert a date/time in the 'America/Chicago' timezone to the local timezone('Australia/Melbourne') in the korn shell.

Please advise with an example.

Regards
Harsha

Answer (score 0):

Go via an ISO 8601 timestamp, which includes the offset:

```
TZ=Australia/Sydney date -d $(TZ=America/Chicago date --i=ns -d "${datep}")
```

to get:

```
Fri May  2 08:31:22 AEST 2014
```

The intermediate time:

```
2014-05-01T17:31:22,000000000-0500
```

is parsed unambiguously and presented however you like in the local timezone.